# Does importing a non-serializable class in a class that implements Serializable breaks Serialization?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

Does importing a non-serializable class in a class that implements Serializable breaks Serialization?

```
import com.xyz.NotSerializableClass;

public class SerializableClass implements Serialiazble{

   public SerializableClass(NotSerializableClass notSerialiazble){
       //do something to notSerialiazble
  }
}
```

Can I still use instances of SerializableClass to pass as an extra in an intent for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly it is you're doing to `NotSerializableClass`. As long as `SerializableClass` does not retain a reference to `NotSerializableClass` you should be fine, but there are many subtle ways in which a reference can be kept, such as:

- Referring to variable `notSerialiazble` from within a Lambda expression defined in the constructor
- Referring to variable `notSerialiazble` from within an anonymous inner class created in the constructor

And of course a few less subtle ways:

- Adding `NotSerializableClass` as a field
- Adding `NotSerializableClass` as a field inside an inner class of `SerializableClass`

And possible a few more, these are just off the top of my head

Comment: As shown in the snippet,I'm using it as a parameter to the constructor. I map it to another object of Class that implements Serializable  and that's it. I don't keep any references.

Comment: Then you should be safe.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating different scenarios where reference is kept.